# Connect to MSSQL with PHP (Linux)

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, debian

Debian 7 x64, MSSQL 2008

Installed:

- PHP 5.4.36-0
- FreeTSD 0.91
- unixodbc

If I connect with:

```
tsql -S server_name -U user_name -P password -D db_name
```

all is ok, but if I try to connect via php:

```
mssql_connect('server_name', 'user_name', 'password')
```

it always says

> Login failed for user 'user_name'. (severity 14)

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

update: Found a solution: make the password shorter and everything was fine. Old password contains 32 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366351%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

"To increase security, the error message that is returned to the client deliberately hides the nature of the authentication error. However, in the SQL Server error log, a corresponding error contains an error state that maps to an authentication failure condition. Compare the error state to the following list to determine the reason for the login failure."

Comment: Login failed for user 'user_name'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.

Comment: Found a solution: make the password shorter and everything was fine. Old password contains 32 characters.

Comment: well, glad to help (: